# Does macOS Sierra do mac address randomisation? I know that iOS does it

Tags: macos, command-line, security, privacy

Does macOS Sierra do mac address randomisation?
I ask if because wonder if I need to run [SpoofMAC](https://github.com/feross/SpoofMAC) when in hotel or foreigns hotspots (mobile MacBook Air)

```
brew install spoof-mac
spoof-mac list
sudo brew services start spoof-mac
sudo spoof-mac randomize en0
```

Comment: I assume since you're not normally walking around all day with your laptop wifi on and looking for networks it's much less of a potential issue so Apple doesn't bother. Is this something you're actually worried about, or just curious?

Comment: @ToddDabney in public transport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natively, no, but you can change the MAC address yourself.  I think it reverts upon reboot though.

The command is `sudo ifconfig <interface> ether <new mac address>`

For example, `sudo ifconfig en0 ether 12:34:56:12:34:56`

You may need to toggle the interface as well `sudo ifconfig en0 down` and up

As per this site (https://blog.macsales.com/37428-tech-tip-finding-and-changing-your-mac-address-in-os-x) you can make a random MAC like this

```
openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//'
```